# How to solve a substring question in DSA. i understand the question but cannot form the logic. I am confused whether to recurssion or loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, queue, stack

Let's call a sequence of brackets balanced if :

Starts with an opening bracket

Ends with a closing bracket

At any point the number of closing brackets does not exceed the number of opening brackets.

The number of opening bracket is same as the number of closing bracket.

We call a balanced sequence of brackets n-balanced if there are n consecutive opening brackets followed by n closing brackets.

From the string n-balanced substrings are removed and the substring to the left and right of the deleted substring is concatenated.

You need to repeatedly remove n-balanced substrings until no more n-balanced substrings exist.

Input Input Format The input consists of multiple testcases.

The first line contains an integer t - the number of testcases.

The next 2*t lines contains the description of the t testcases.

The first line of each testcase contains a string s - the sequence of brackets.

The second line of each testcase contains the integer n.

Constraints 1 ≤ t ≤ 10^3

1 ≤ |s| ≤ 10^4

1 ≤ n ≤ 10^2

Output Output Format For each testcase print the remaining string after performing all the removals, or -1 if the string becomes empty.

> Sample Input
> 3
> ((())())()
> 2
> ((()))
> 3
> ))((
> 2
>
> Sample Output
> ()
> -1
> ))((

Comment: Saw this question a couple days ago, if it wasn't you, then search for it, it's definitely been asked before

Comment: oh, never mind - it was closed, even though that person at least wrote code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78018332/can-someone-help-me-an-tell-me-how-to-approach-the-problem maybe you could get some inspiration